# What's the class of eclipse pref table

Tags: java, eclipse, preference

Could you tell me, what is the class of this table like widget [image: with browsing feature]

It's eclipse->window->preferences->java->build path->classpath variables? or if you know how to get it's preference page class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That page is `org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.preferences.ClasspathVariablesPreferencePage`

The actual class path list is a `TableViewer` using a label provider that implements `IColorProvider` (at least it was, the coloring has been dropped in Eclipse Neon).